# Can't run a simple main class within a micronaut project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

Within a fresh micronaut 4 project, I can't run a simple main class I was trying to test with, literally a `System.out.println()` without it throwing an error:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks…
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Copying resources... [system]
Parsing java… [system]
java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (20.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (https://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (https://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
java: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor could not be instantiated
java:   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:586)
java:   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:813)
java:   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:729)
java:   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1403)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.Iterators$10.next(Iterators.java:214)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Iterators$CompoundIterator.next(Iterators.java:69)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:821)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:919)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1262)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1377)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:930)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:239)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.lambda$compileJava$2(JavaBuilder.java:519)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.invokeJavac(JavaBuilder.java:582)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:517)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:361)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:286)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:240)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1556)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1185)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1336)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1150)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:918)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:474)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:197)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:150)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:387)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:212)
java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:211)
java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
java: Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.micronaut.core.async.converters.ReactiveTypeConverterRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void register(io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService)' of interface io.micronaut.core.convert.TypeConverterRegistrar.
java:   at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.registerDefaultConverters(DefaultConversionService.java:965)
java:   at io.micronaut.core.convert.DefaultConversionService.<init>(DefaultConversionService.java:102)
java:   at io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService.<clinit>(ConversionService.java:36)
java:   at io.micronaut.core.convert.value.ConvertibleValuesMap.<init>(ConvertibleValuesMap.java:54)
java:   at io.micronaut.core.convert.value.ConvertibleValues.<clinit>(ConvertibleValues.java:39)
java:   at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.AbstractInjectAnnotationProcessor.<init>(AbstractInjectAnnotationProcessor.java:71)
java:   at io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor.<init>(TypeElementVisitorProcessor.java:84)
java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
java:   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:789)
java:   ... 35 more
java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
Checking dependencies… [system]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Errors occurred while compiling module 'system'
javac 20.0.2 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches…
Compilation failed: errors: 1; warnings: 0
Executing post-compile tasks…
Compilation failed: errors: 1; warnings: 0
Synchronizing output directories…
07/08/2023, 09:14 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 992 ms
```

I suspect [the Receiver class does implement the method](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/4.0.x/core-reactive/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/async/converters/ReactiveTypeConverterRegistrar.java#L34), but maybe I'm missing something. Is this a micronaut issue, is it really a compiler bug (sounds unlikely), am I doing something daft in my IDE?

Comment: I know nothing about Micronaut, but reading the error, it appears that you are missing a dependency. Could be wildly wrong though.

Comment: Please add some code and/or tell us how to reproduce this error. BR